# Why is my PowerPoint question still closed even though I added more details?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, moderation

My question ["How can I disable "small caps" in my text in PowerPoint 365 on the web?"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/171637) ([archive.org snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20230812045619/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171637/how-can-i-disable-small-caps-in-my-text-in-powerpoint-365-on-the-web)) was closed by a mod as "needs details or clarity."

In response, I added more details but the question remains closed. Why?

Comments were moved to chat and I reviewed [that transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64167372#64167372) but I still don't understand why the question is still closed.

For example, the mod wrote:

> This is an esoteric problem and troubleshooting it is not a good fit for the site.  [Author: [Blind Spots](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/559556/blind-spots)]

Is the question still closed because the mod thinks it's an esoteric problem? A troubleshooting question? Is it because it still "needs details or clarity?" Or, is there another reason?